# Got problem when I'm using join on in database by sqlyog

Tags: mysql, sql

I created multiple tables and used a `JOIN` to retrieve specific data:

[image: these are the tables]

I used the following query:

```sql
SELECT c.SUBJECT1, c.SUBJECT2,c.SUBJECT3,l.NAME   
FROM  LECTURER l JOIN 
COURSE c ON (l.LECT_ID = c.LECT1 OR  l.LECT_ID = c.LECT2 OR l.LECT_ID = c.LECT3)  
 OR (c.LECT1 = c.SUBJECT1 AND c.LECT2 = c.SUBJECT2 AND c.LECT3 = c.SUBJECT3) 
WHERE l.LECT_ID = 'L056'
```

The problem is when I want to show the subjects taught by Ahmed (`L056`), it display the table but also add extra data that isn't required.

What am I doing wrong in my query?

Comment: The second sets of `OR` in your join doesn't make sense. Just use the first condition.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to show what would be your the expected results of the query, say for teacher Ahmed (`L056`)?

Comment: This line `OR (c.LECT1 = c.SUBJECT1 AND c.LECT2 = c.SUBJECT2 AND c.LECT3 = c.SUBJECT3) ` is completely useless for what you want.

Comment: Despite that, I've tested your query with the exact table and data (I skipped `STUDENT` table because it wasn't used in the query) and I only get result where Ahmad (L056) **with no other extra data is present**. I would agree with @GMB that you should show your expected result